# Is the expression that allocates memory rvalue expression or lvalue expression?

Tags: c++

Let say I have the following code

```
int main(){
    new int; // Is this expression l-value or r-value??

    return 0;

}
```

I know that lvalues are persistent object (since it has specific place in memory from where we can access latter even after the expression ends) and rvalues are temporary object (it has no place in memory and vaporizes after the expression ends).

I saw some where that it is rvalue expression. How can it be rvalue if the expression returns an address ( a specific place in memory). Or Is it rvalue because what ever the expression new int returns (an address value), it vanishes and could never be caught after the expression ends.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`new int` is an r-value.

You can't use:

```
int i;
(new int) = &i;
```

Perhaps you are thinking of the object whose address is returned by `new int`.
The expression denoting the object whose address is returned, `*(new int)`, is an l-value. You can use:

```
*(new int) = 10;
```

That's not good code. It leaks memory, but it is legal code.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it is an r-value before C++11, and a pr-value after C++11, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111, yes it is a prvalue starting from C++11.

Comment: @Rakete1111 prvalues are a subset of rvalues, so you could say it was an rvalue in all versions.

Comment: but in expression  ---> int x = *(new int); <--- *(new int)  is rvalue right? So does that mean the compiler at this point did lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ..

Comment: @pokche, an rvalue can be used where an lvalue is expected. I can't think of a situation where that is not true.

Comment: @pokche, `*x` is not *any* sort of conversion of `x`, it's a dereference. You may be thinking of the conversion done in something like `int *x = new int;` - while `new int` itself may be render an rvalue, `x` is an lvalue (or some variant thereof).

Comment: @paxdiablo what about if int *x = new int(2); int *y = new int(3); *x = *y; ... I know *x is lvalue and *y is rvalue here... doesn't lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happen here?

Comment: @pokche, please don't make this a consulting session. Experiment with code. If you have any questions on any specific code, ask a different question.

Comment: @pokche: you may *think* you know that `*y` is an rvalue but you would be wrong :-) It's not an rvalue just because it's on the right hand side of an assignment, the (simplified) rule is that rvalue cannot appear on the left - that doesn't mean lvalues can't appear on the right (while every dog is a mammal, not every mammal is a dog).

Comment: @paxdiablo I think I got confused between address x and memory in address x ( *x).

Comment: "The object whose address is returned is an l-value." Objects don't have value categories. *Expressions* have value categories.